# How do I change the password from admin_users in db using the salt?

Tags: password

I have a problem with the salt. My password looks like:

```
b59c9d784fad6053bc88d70babd68ec4:sTWR4rQKio6a03pt3in3JkhYN0b2AsBO
```

so I guess the salt is also encrypted. How do i get the salt value ? 
There is another account which have this password:

```
0ae97fa8652ad8165ab28eb66255271c:rp
```

so if i change the password into another like this

`myencryptedpassword:rp` it works fine, but the first if i changed it like this:

```
myencryptedpassword:sTWR4rQKio6a03pt3in3JkhYN0b2AsBO it does not work. Why ? Thx in advance !
```

This is the magento version:

```
public static function getVersionInfo()
    {
        return array(
            'major'     => '1',
            'minor'     => '9',
            'revision'  => '2',
            'patch'     => '0',
            'stability' => '',
            'number'    => '',
        );
    }
```

Comment: Create admin user with easy password and change your password via admin area.

Comment: @zhartaunik I cannot access the admin area. I have just the database and the magento files. I have to change the admin_users table directly :(.

Comment: You can use plain md5 for the password when updating it from the DB. Then you can log into the admin and change it to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into admin_user
select
(select max(user_id) + 1 from admin_user) user_id,
'FIRSTNAME' first_name,
'LASTNAME' last_name,
'TEST@EMAIL.COM' email,
'USERNAME' username,
MD5('PASSWORD') password,
now() created,
NULL modified,
NULL logdate,
0 lognum,
0 reload_acl_flag,
1 is_active,
(select max(extra) from admin_user where extra is not null) extra,
NULL,
NULL;

insert into admin_role
select
(select max(role_id) + 1 from admin_role) role_id,
(select role_id from admin_role where role_name = 'Administrators') parent_id,
2 tree_level,
0 sort_order,
'U' role_type,
(select user_id from admin_user where username = 'USERNAME') user_id,
'USERNAME' role_name
```

Don't forget to set your username and password. This way you can create admin user and via admin area change password to existed user

Comment: I am getting this erros message from the first query: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: What magento version do you have?

Comment: How can I get that ? :D

Comment: open app/Mage.php near row 168 you can find method getVersionInfo() and there will be version. For example:        'major'     => '1',
            'minor'     => '9',
            'revision'  => '1',
            'patch'     => '0',

Comment: I finally found it, I updated my post. Please check it again. Thx

Comment: Yes, I see. Max version I have is 1.9.1.0. In this version query execute well. I'll try to install 1.9.2.0. I think it will take ~10-20 minutes

Comment: OK, I will wait. Thx again :)

Comment: I didn't faced with any troubles executing this query. Try to execute it without any changes. Your username and pass will be: USERNAME PASSWORD. Then you can use following credentials to authorise

Comment: I copy pasted your query and i got this: "<e>Query: insert into admin_user select (select max(user_id) + 1 from admin_user) user_id, 'FIRSTNAME' first_name, 'LASTNAME' last_name, '...

Error Code: 1136
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

Comment: So any idea why I got this ? :)

Comment: go chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26572/admin-password

Comment: I need reputation to chat :(

Comment: did you see my messages?

Comment: I have to go, I will check it later and I will let you know. Thx again for your help !!!

Comment: Yes it works. Thx for the sharing that file !!! :D maybe you can post it in your answer

Comment: Glad to hear that everything is working well. Don't want to share it public

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at installing [N98 MageRun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) then from the command line you'd then need to run `n98-magerun.phar admin:user:change-password` and follow the prompts. A must for any developer :D